# Sonicwall 2650 Set public IP on Transparent (L3 Bridged)

Tags: networking, sonicwall

I'm having problems configuring my Sonicwall 2650.

We have a small range of public IPs on a leased line, most of these are used, via nat, to go to public servers. However we would like to share our connection with a client and have them visible on one of our specific public IPs.

I have setup a zone with public security and an interface in Transparent mode with a single IP specified as the transparent range. The router (or laptop) plugged into that port has a static IP of the one that I chose for the transparent range and can get internet just fine but no matter what I do, when connected through that port if I check my public IP I get the main IP that is used for the rest of the network to get internet. Am I misunderstanding how the transparent mode should be working or have I configured something incorrectly?

Here is the zone configuration:
[image: Zone Configuration]

And the interface configuration:

[image: Interface Config]

Do I need to setup a static route or NAT policy for this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include enough detail to be able to answer the question. For example, you talk about the the configurations, but you do not include them. We cannot guess what you are doing wrong, so edit the question to include the configurations and what configurations you are trying.

Comment: Please list out the text configuration from the CLI and post it into the question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`) that is right next to the image option you used. obfuscate any public addresses and passwords. IANA has set aside three address ranges for IPv4 and one for IPv6 for you to use as example address ranges instead of the actual addresses: `192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, `203.0.113.0/24`, and `2001:db8::/32`.

Comment: Hi Ron, That's a 2.7mb text file, is there any specific part of the file that would be useful?